# R, Create a new column based on non-numeric value of another column

Tags: r, if-statement, dataset

I'm still relatively new to R, so pardon if what I'm saying lacks proper and explicit terminology.

I have a data set created from a UDP stream set up to collect data from one source and time from another source. The time is added asynchronously, meaning that one column contains information (Start, Stop) but the rest of such rows are blank. The link below may help explain what exactly this looks like in a data set.

https://googledrive.com/host/0Bw82Tt1bj-QRUkxwdGY2Qm5UOVk

I want to read where in column "MarkersOri" "Start" is located, and print "Start" in a new column "MarkerNew" exactly one row down. (Subsequently, I plan to delete these mostly blank rows and the "MarkersOri" column)

I have tried to implement if statements and the findInterval command, but I couldn't find anything on doing exactly what I want to do.

EDIT: Solved. Appreciate the help.

Comment: A good way to get people to help you is to post your data and what code you have tried so far, to get a small subset of your data use this command: `dput(your.data[1:10,]` and then paste the results inside your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll be sure to follow this procedure next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a new columns, with just 'Start' inside, but shifteb by one row down?

Maybe this might help:

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:10], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$col1[5] <- 'Start'

# create empty column
df$newcol <- NA
# shift 'Start' by one row down, store it in the new column
df$newcol[which(df$col1 == 'Start') + 1] <- 'Start'
df
```